# how to calculate (date - duration) in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I reduce a specific duration from a date?
for example -

the base date and time to reduce from

> 15/05/2018 02:00:00

the duration to reduce -

> 03:00:00 hours

the expected output -

> 14/05/2018 23:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=A1-3/24-5/(24*60)-55/(24*60*60)`

where

- A1 = 15/05/2018 02:00:00
- 3 = the number of hours to reduce
- 5 = minutes
- 55 = seconds

If you have time in format: 03:05:55, the formula is simple:

`=A1 - A2`

where

- A1 = 15/05/2018 02:00:00
- A2 = 03:05:55

Comment: what if I have time accuracy by seconds. let's say - the time to reduce is 03:05:55